# (Unity) does NativeArray<T0>.Copy, or NativeArray<T0>.CopyTo, allocate any memory?

Tags: unity, c#

1. Is there any memory allocation if there are two arrays of the same size and same type? If they are already of the same length, and the values are of struct, when there's the copy, is any more memory used? Like, is it the same as if I did a for loop setting values from one array to the other?
2. Are they the same?
   https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Collections.NativeArray_1.CopyTo.html
   https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Collections.NativeArray_1.Copy.html

[What should I write here? Is this enough for a question?]

Comment: You can see the options are not the same by just reviewing the links you shared. `Copy` allows copying just a range of elements to an offset position in another array, while `CopyTo` copies all elements in the array to another of the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NativeArray<T>.Copy()
nativeArray.CopyTo()
nativeArray.CopyFrom()
```

Those methods do not allocate memory, that's the point.

> is it the same as if I did a for loop setting values from one array to
> the other?

This is faster than manual copy operation:

```
// link* credits = https://gist.github.com/LotteMakesStuff/6198f966e414a88d1337b0360cb891f5
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe;

public unsafe static void MemCpy <SRC,DST> ( NativeArray<SRC> src , DST[] dst )
    where SRC : unmanaged
    where DST : unmanaged
{
    //ASSERTION: sizeof(SRC)<=sizeof(DST)
    fixed( void* arrayPointer = dst )
    {
        UnsafeUtility.MemCpy(
            arrayPointer ,
            NativeArrayUnsafeUtility.GetUnsafeBufferPointerWithoutChecks(src) ,
            src.Length * (long)UnsafeUtility.SizeOf<SRC>()
        );
    }
}
public unsafe static void MemCpy <SRC,DST> ( SRC[] src , NativeArray<DST> dst )
    where SRC : unmanaged
    where DST : unmanaged
{
    //ASSERTION: sizeof(SRC)<=sizeof(DST)
    //ASSERTION: dst.IsCreated==true
    fixed( void* bufferPointer = src )
    {
        UnsafeUtility.MemCpy(
            NativeArrayUnsafeUtility.GetUnsafeBufferPointerWithoutChecks(dst) ,
            bufferPointer ,
            src.Length * (long)UnsafeUtility.SizeOf<SRC>()
        );
    }
}
```